# Error NoStackTraceTimeoutException with quarkus client

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-native

I have an rest service than consume other rest service on another server with a latency between 1500 and 3000 ms.

If i send a few request all works fine.

But if i make load test and send 200 request/seg I get too many errors of timeOut

io.vertx.core.http.impl.NoStackTraceTimeoutException: The timeout of 4000 ms has been exceeded when getting a connection to

So, I tested only the second service and it works fine.

Client to Second service

```
@Path("/zonificacion")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "zoning-api")
@RequestScoped
public interface ZoningDao {
    @GET
    Uni<ResponseDTO> getBannersAsUni(@QueryParam(value = "latitud") Double latitude, @QueryParam(value = "longitud") Double longitude);
}
```

My service

```
@GET
    @Path("/getBannersAsUni")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<ResponseDTO> getBannersAsUni() {
        Uni<ResponseDTO> response = zoningDao.getBannersAsUni(19.4092305, -99.090939);
        return response;
    }
```

Can anyone help me or have an idea

Comment: Have you tried `quarkus.rest-client.zone-api.connect-timeout=3000ms`?

Comment: Yes, i configure both times connect-timeout and response-timeout. If i send 10 requests it work good. But when I send 50/seg per 30 seconds, I get too many timeOuts